# What to use if websockets are not supported by my vps

Tags: node.js, websocket, server

I have tried the chat exemple of socket.io on my vps but i did not work so i contacted the support and it turned out that websockets are not supported.

Does anyone have any idea of what to use as an alternative for a chat app ??

Thank you.

Comment: Longpolling is your only other, unsustainable for a chat app, option. Get a new VPS

Comment: Any recommendations ?? because i saw that most popular ones also don't support websockets.